# Json file only appends first hit of python script

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I've a python script that runs through a directory, searches for a string and prints out the file and line when the string is read

```
for check_configs in glob.glob('/etc/ansible/logs/*.txt'):
    with open(check_configs) as f:
        for line in f:
            #find which line string occurs
            data = []
            if 'test' in line:
                data.append({'File':check_configs,'Line':line})
                print data
                #print file and line in json file
                with open('/etc/ansible/results/get_ip_check', 'w') as outfile:
                    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)      
            else:
                #if not in line continue to next line/file
                continue
```

For debugging purposes, I've included the line *print data* just to print what I get. This prints out every time the string occurs,

```
[{'Line': 'test\n', 'File': '/my/test/dir/logs/log2.txt'}]

[{'Line': 'test other test config\n', 'File': '/my/test/dir/logs/log1.txt'}]
```

however the json file only prints out one occurrence of the string

```
[
    {
        "Line": "test\n", 
        "File": "/my/test/dir/logs/log1.txt"
    }
]
```

Am I missing something with the json loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you open the file every time within the loop and just dump the value from the current iteration, overwriting whatever has gone before.

You should define `data` before the beginning of the loop, and move the open and dump to after the end of the loop, so that data is accumulated within the loop and you only write once.

(Note also, `else: continue` is pointless since that is what happens anyway; remove those lines.)

```
data = []
for check_configs in glob.glob('/etc/ansible/logs/*.txt'):
    with open(check_configs) as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'test' in line:
                data.append({'File':check_configs,'Line':line})

with open('/etc/ansible/results/get_ip_check', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: That's the one, couldn't see where I was going back on myself

Answer (score 3):

You reset `data` to the empty list `[]` in each loop. You have to move it out of the loop:

```
for check_configs in glob.glob('/etc/ansible/logs/*.txt'):
    with open(check_configs) as f:
        data = []   # We create the empty data once before the loop
        for line in f:
            #find which line string occurs
            if 'test' in line:
                data.append({'File':check_configs,'Line':line})
                print data
                #print file and line in json file

            else:
                #if not in line continue to next line/file
                continue

with open('/etc/ansible/results/get_ip_check', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```